# Concat string with number in kdb+ q

Tags: kdb, q

I can append a string with number.

```
temp:30
text:"Current temperature is ",string temp
show text
type text
```

Result

```
"Current temperature is 30"
10h
```

However, if I append one more string, it becomes a list. (why?)

```
text:"Current temperature is ",string temp," degree celsius"
show text
type text
```

Result

```
C
u
r
r
e
n
t
 
t
e
m
p
e
r
a
t
u
r
e
 
i
s
..
0h
```

I can use `sv` with empty string as delimiter, is it the normal way to do it?

```
text:"" sv ("Current temperature is ";string temp;" degree celsius")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change it to

```
text:"Current temperature is ",string [temp]," degree celsius"
```

Your string function is working on: temp," degree celsius" but you just need to string[temp] to concat it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything like printf in q? So I can use %d instead.

Comment: You have to convert it into a function instead then. -1 is an internal function to print string to console. 
Something like: `f:{[temp] -1 text:"Current temperature is ",string[temp]," degree celsius"}` then you can use `f temp`

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Maurice Lim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76844301/10871073), this is because of the way q evaluates expressions. Expressions are evaluated left-of-right (which means expressions are evaluated right-to-left).

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/4_Operators/#412-left-of-right-evaluation

The concatenation operator therefore works first on

```
temp," degree celsius"
```

which becomes a mixed list. And mixed lists are displayed exactly the way you got your first result.

Using square brackets, changes the order of evaluation (because it binds temp to the function string) and therefore evaluates `string[temp]` first. Then you concatenate two strings which returns a simple list.

Answer (score 0):

`comma operator` treats each character in the `concatenated string` as a separate item and creates a `list` of those characters.

On the other hand, when you use `sv` with an empty string as the delimiter, it joins all the strings in the list into a single string, which is the desired behavior for concatenation.